# Use variable to access class property

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data class (simplified)

```
public class Transport
{
    public int TransId;
    public string TType;
    public string Color;
    public string Size;
}

Transport t1 = new Transport();
populate(t1)
```

With which I am populating textbox controls on a windows form. My textboxes have the same names (`TransId, TType, Color, Size`).  There are many more so what I am trying to do is use the name of the textbox to access the data.  Something like....

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    tb.Text = t1.(tb.Name);
}
```

Is this possible?  Is it even a good idea or should I stick to `TransId.Text = t1.TransId` etc?

Comment: _"Is it even a good idea"_ No.  Reflection would make this possible but you would lose compile-time safety. You should not rely your business logic on control-names which could change. If you really need you could use a `Dictinary<string, Transport>` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why don't you write an answer and tell him why it isn't a good idea instead?

Comment: @TylerD87 Too constructive for this site.  They prefer to be arrogant and sarcastic from what I see!.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for updating for comment to explain why not.  Helps with the learning process if you know what I mean.

Comment: @FlipTop: there's no day without this question. So with a little bit of search effort you would find several answers. Apart from that i don't see the sarcasm in my comment (btw, i haven't downvoted).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Then I apologise.  I couldnt find it but I did look. Maybe one of the problems with learning new things is that we have no idea what to search for. i wasn't talking of you directly but browsing this site I see many un constuctive comments that do not help posters one bit.  Especially to new users.  That said some people seem really helpful, new user like me just hope we get a response from such a person. Im not here for points to massage my ego just here to hopefully learn something.  The downvote matters not a jot! :)

Comment: No it's not a good idea, but I'm glad to see you've actually verified this before using it. Isn't that what this site is all about? I have some terrible ideas sometimes, StackOverflow makes me realise though.

On a completely unrelated note, I hate downvotes on questions like this, especially without feedback. You're asking for clarification something you're not sure about, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @JoeStead My point exactly! Im sure I will have many more bad ideas but how will I know if I dont ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to assign properties values to controls manually (especially if you want only displaying of values) or use Data Binding to bind class properties to controls:

- Select one of TextBoxes and go to *(DataBindings)* property
- For `Text` binding select *Add Project Data Source...* option
- Select *Object* data source type
- Select your `Transport` type

That will add `transportBindingSource` to your application. Now you can select each TextBox and bind it to one of properties from your `Transport` object:

[image]

All you need now is add `Transport` instance to binding source:

```
private Transport transport;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    transport = new Transport { 
                   TransId = 42, 
                   Color = "White", 
                   Size = "Big"
                   // ...
                };

    transportBindingSource.Add(transport);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Nice benefit of binding is that it works both ways - when you'll edit value in TextBox, transport object property will be updated.

---

NOTE: Consider to use `PropertyGrid` if you just want to show values of all properties of object:

```
 propertyGrid.SelectedObject = transport;
```

[image]

Comment: I've already upvoted this, but you keep updating it and making it better.

Comment: @JoeStead thanks :) I promise to stop making it better... soon

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy This is what I was after but far more than I was expecting!  Thank you for taking the time and making an effort to answer my question.